# instance access to class members of inherited abstract

Tags: c#

This is theory Thursday I guess.

Shouldn't Main() have access to _XLocal & _YLocal?

```
using System;

namespace HelloGoodbyeOperator {

    public abstract class HGOperator {
        public string _greeting { get; set; }
        public bool _x { get; internal set; }
        public bool _y { get; internal set; }

        public static implicit operator HGOperator(bool mode) {
            object ret = new object();
            if (mode)
                ret = new HGOperator_Hello { _greeting = "hello", _XLocal = 10 };
            else
                ret = new HGOperator_Goodbye { _greeting = "goodbye", _YLocal = 20 };

            return (HGOperator)ret;
        }
    }



    public class HGOperator_Hello : HGOperator { 
        public int _XLocal { get; set; }
        public HGOperator_Hello() { _x = true; Console.WriteLine("HGOperator_Hello //" + _XLocal.ToString() + "\\\\"); }
    }



    public class HGOperator_Goodbye : HGOperator { 
        public int _YLocal { get; set; }
        public HGOperator_Goodbye() { _y = false; Console.WriteLine("HGOperator_Goodbye //", _YLocal, "\\\\"); }

    }



    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            HGOperator hg = true;
            Console.WriteLine(hg._greeting);
            test(hg);

            Console.WriteLine("");

            hg = false;
            Console.WriteLine(hg._greeting);
            test(hg);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void test(HGOperator hg) {
            if (hg is HGOperator_Hello) {
                Console.WriteLine(hg._x);
                //Console.WriteLine(hg._XLocal);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine(hg._y);
                //Console.WriteLine(hg._YLocal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

> HGOperator_Hello //0\
>
> hello
>
> True
>
> HGOperator_Goodbye //
>
> goodbye
>
> False

I can understand how trying to access hg._YLocal of a HGOperator_Hello type would be a nightmare & vise-versa.  But would still think I could get to the respective members with caution.

Also and I will bet this is realted.  The two concrete constructors do not have a value for _XLocal & _YLocal on the Console.Writeline()s.  Without the .ToString() just a "" is printed. Why not?
Thanks.

Comment: where is `Main`?  what is the question?

Comment: @GlennFerrie where is always is.  Lol.  `class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler doesn't know that `hg` is a derived type of `HGOperator_Hello` or `HGOperator_Goodbye`. So inside your `if` you need to create another variable and cast it:

```
if (hg is HGOperator_Hello)
{
    var helloHg = (HGOperator_Hello)hg;
    Console.WriteLine(helloHg._x);
    Console.WriteLine(helloHg._XLocal);
}
else
{
    var goodbyeHg = (HGOperator_Goodbye)hg;
    Console.WriteLine(goodbyeHg._y);
    Console.WriteLine(goodbyeHg._YLocal);
}
```

Comment: Huh!  I never would have seen it.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I just had this realization.  if-is in fact proves the compiler does know hg is a  _Hello class.  I'm not saying your answer is at all wrong.  I'm just saying the compiler _could_ be given a little smarter feature here.  I realize the if() test is more of a run-time challenge but the system_could_ have the smarts to know that, pre-compile, if-true then hg must be a _Hello.  Version next I guess.